# Not able to download file from AWS S3 Access Denied Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

When I try to download one file from AWS S3 through console, I am getting following error:

This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it.

The document tree is shown below.

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>DF19E559FDBA71C2</RequestId>
<HostId>f5cIaO8eh2yTmC+rtVIVg54xY4EXAjG6lsxzjbBjzMRwDWaMFaggAU3Wyoipy2ZuDHQLhz402DE=</HostId>
</Error>
```

Can someone please help with this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This seems like client side error. Your browser is most probably misinterpreting response type, incorrectly thinking it is XML - `text/xml`. What kind of file are you trying to download?

Comment: Thanks for your help but I tried it through programmatic access and getting same error. So I dont think so its browser issue  
The full error is mentioned below
`<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>DF19E559FDBA71C2</RequestId>
<HostId>
f5cIaO8eh2yTmC+rtVIVg54xY4EXAjG6lsxzjbBjzMRwDWaMFaggAU3Wyoipy2ZuDHQLhz402DE=
</HostId>
</Error>`

Comment: The "document tree" message is not an error, just an informational message from the browser, which you can (and should) disregard. The error is `Access Denied` and if you are getting the same error with CLI/SDK/API access then you have a problem with the credentials or the permissions (or are not making the intended request) and your question will need to be much more specific.

Comment: Does this fail if you log out of the AWS console, log back in, and then retry?

Comment: Check if you're the owner of the object or it was uploaded by some other account and it didn't give you any permission ?

Answer (score 15):

You are getting this error because the file is set to private and you don't have the permission do download it. To do so, you must set a [Bucket Policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html) according to the permissions you with to use.

If you want any user to be able to download bucket objects, you can set a policy such as:

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid":"PublicRead",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action":["s3:GetObject"],
      "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Another option, if you want to serve content, is to use [Amazon CloudFront](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) as a CDN.

Finally, it is important to understand what kind of access you need to download your files to set the appropriate policy.

Comment: This is not working on my side. I can download files I uploaded myself but not the ones uploaded by another party.